# Handler is not working inside View Holder in Android

Tags: android, handler

I am trying to make a `RecyclerView` with auto-image-slider with **ViewPager** inside a **ViewHolder** class.
The Problem is handler is executed , but the `onPageChangeListener` is not working though.
Let's call this as ***adView***

```
public class BannerViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder<BannerResponse> {

@BindView(R.id.adViewPager)
ViewPager adViewPager;
@BindView(R.id.dotIndicator)
PageIndicatorView indicator;
private ImageViewPagerAdapter mImagePagerAdapter;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private int bannerImageSize = 0;
private int currentPage = 0;

private final Runnable sliderPage = () -> {
    currentPage++;
    if (currentPage == bannerImageSize - 1) {
        currentPage = 0;
    }
};

public BannerViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    mImagePagerAdapter = new ImageViewPagerAdapter(itemView.getContext());
}


@Override
public void setData(BannerResponse mData) {
    if (mData != null && mData.getBannerList() != null && !mData.getBannerList().isEmpty()) {
        mImagePagerAdapter.setData(mData.getBannerList());
        adViewPager.setAdapter(mImagePagerAdapter);
        bannerImageSize = mData.getBannerList().size();
        indicator.setViewPager(adViewPager);
        handler.postDelayed(sliderPage, 1000);
        adViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                indicator.setSelection(position);
                currentPage = position;
                handler.removeCallbacks(sliderPage);
                handler.postDelayed(sliderPage, 2000);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }
}}
```

When this adView is done outside of the `RecyclerView`, not as a part of cardItem inside the `RecyclerView`, it was working. But, this is not working when it is implemented inside a `ViewHolder` of a `RecyclerView`. 
`View` got inflated, slider is not working.

***EDITED*** -
And I also want to know the effects of declaring **Handler** and **Runnable** in **ViewHolder** . Can it lead have memory leaks? If so, How can I avoid it?

Comment: Try to call `handler.removeCallbacks(sliderPage);` before when you call your `handler` first time

Comment: May I know why? btw, it's still not working.

Comment: **viewPager.startAutoScroll();  
viewPager.setInterval(3000);**  Have you tried using these properties ? Probably trying this would give you a clue of where the trouble is.

Comment: can't use startAutoScroll() , only startNestedScroll(int Axes) is available

Answer (score 1):

```
private final Runnable sliderPage = () -> {
  currentPage++;
  if (currentPage == bannerImageSize - 1) {
    currentPage = 0;
  }
  viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
};
```